# Store controls' custom attributes in viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback, viewstate

I add "readonly" attribute to ASP.NET controls in some event handlers.

```
control.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

But these attributes are not stored in viewstate and after postback these attributes are cleared. How can I make it stay after postback? Using `control.ReadOnly = true;` is not applicable because it makes control disabled and therefore ugly.
Thank you everybody for help!

Comment: you can use the disabled attribute and set css class for the disabled inputs like input[disabled] { backgroundcolor:beautifull;opacity:less ; }

Comment: @2GDev disabled elements do not allow to change text color. It can only be grey. Try this: <input disabled="disabled" style="color:Red" value="Some text here"/> and see that your color will not be red as specified in css style. Thank you for suggestion!

Comment: Are these controls derived from WebControl or Control?

Answer (score -2):

This is an example style applied to disabled input text...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
input[disabled]
{
    background-color:White; 
    border:0 solid #fff;
    color:red;
}
</style>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="disabled"  value="i'm disabled!"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested on Google Chroome 13.0.782.112 on Windows 7.

Comment: However, color does not work neither in Opera nor in IE7/IE8. I cannot force users to install Google Chrome to see red color in disabled inputs. Thank you for suggestion!